# error with query REPLACE using mysql PDO

Tags: replace, pdo

I try to execute the following mysql query with pdo

```
REPLACE INTO session SET id = :id, user_id = :user_id, data = :data, timestamp = :timestamp
```

and I get the following error:

```
[18-Sep-2014 11:48:10] Exception Message: Unhandled Exception.
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?, data = ?, timestamp = ?' at line 1.
```

You can find the error back in the log.:

```
Query:REPLACE INTO session SET id = :id, user_id = :user_id, data = :data, timestamp = :timestamp
```

Params:

```
Array
(
    [id] => sv9o264ciicsfd8porp1v0gl46
    [user_id] => 0
    [data] => version|s:8:"computer";linkedin|a:1:{s:5:"state";s:7:"Q7HXzKo";}github|a:1:{s:5:"state";s:7:"Q7HXzKo";}
    [timestamp] => 1411030090
)
```

My Table session structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `session` (
  `id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_id` mediumint(10) NOT NULL,
  `data` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` int(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `session` (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

When I use phpmyadmin to execute it is working fine.
Can you help me to understand what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten an equal sign.
Change this part of your query:

```
user_id :user_id
```

to:

```
user_id = :user_id
```

I also think there may be a problem in using a reserved keyword like `timestamp` for one of your columns, try changing it to something like `tstamp`. You could also try to quote the name in the query.

```
REPLACE INTO session SET `id` = :id, `user_id` = :user_id, `data` = :data, `timestamp` = :timestamp
```

Comment: Well Sorry I mistyped, I still get the same error: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number

Comment: Is it possible to be connected with unique and primary key?? I get also SQL: [95] REPLACE INTO session SET id = :id, user_id = :user_id, data = :data, timestamp = :timestamp
 Params: 1 Key: Name: [10] :timestamp paramno=3 name=[10] ":timestamp" is_param=1 param_type=2

Answer (score 0):

well I found it, very silly mistake: I should separate the , from the parameter:

I changed this 

`:user_id,`

to:

`:user_id ,`